# Concatenating Strings in columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
declare @tab1 table (
    descrizione varchar(50),
    c_prodotto char(5),
)

insert into @tabRiepilogoProvvigioniBanca (descrizione, c_prodotto)
select c_prodotto, descrizione
from Maintable
```

The result of this query return 2 records.

Then i want to print them :

```
select  @riga   = ''

select  @riga   = @riga + substring( ltrim(rtrim( c_prodotto)) + space(10), 1, 10)
from @tab1
select  @riga   = @riga + ' ' + substring(ltrim(rtrim(ISNULL( descrizione,0))) + space(50), 1, 15) 
from @tab1

select @riga
```

The result is :

```
PVDTR PVTDC    0 0
```

I want to know if is it possible to have a result like this :

```
PVDTR   0
PVTDC   0
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from your `Maintable` table?

Comment: Did you mean `insert into @tab1` instead of `insert into @tabRiepilogoProvvigioniBanca` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the two `select` statements that fill `@riga` into one `select` statement, and also add a linebreak after each row, as follows:

```
select @riga = @riga
             + substring(ltrim(rtrim(c_prodotto)) + space(10), 1, 10)
             + ' '
             + substring(ltrim(rtrim(ISNULL(descrizione,0))) + space(50), 1, 15)
             + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
from @tab1
```

Comment: this gie me this result : PVDTR 0 PVTDC  0, but i want them in 2 different columns

Comment: Have you tried `PRINT @riga`? In SSMS, a SELECT normally shows data in a grid which filters away the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont use @riga, you can just select rows

```
select  substring( ltrim(rtrim( c_prodotto)) + space(10), 1, 10) 
+ ' ' + substring(ltrim(rtrim(ISNULL( descrizione,0))), 1, 15) 
from @tab1
```